# Using the temp directory for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-functions-runtime, azure-files

I have a set of Azure functions running on the same host, which scales up to many instances at times. I'd like to store a very small amount of ephemeral data (a few kb's) and opportunistically share those data between function executions. I know that the temp directory is only available to the functions running on that same instance. I also know that I could use the home directory, durable functions, or other Azure (such as blob) storage to share data between all functions persistently.

I have two main questions

1. What are the security implications of using the temp directory? Who can access its contents outside of the running function?
2. Is this still a reasonable solution? I can't find much in the way of Microsoft documentation outside of what looks like some outdated kudu documentation [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system).

Thanks!

Comment: why not cache your data in table storage? you shouldnt need to roll your own storage mechanism. do you want me to show you how to do this?

Comment: Thanks! I do know how to, but was trying to avoid adding an additional piece of infrastructure, even if minimal (especially given my security needs). I did find an alternative solution - storing the data in memory as a static value that is lazy initialized (and updated/gotten in a thread safe manner). All functions on the host share memory, so this is actually a must faster and safe solution. It's not technically an answer to my question, so I didn't mark it.

Comment: as your function scales it, all of your instances are not guaranteed to be on the same vm, and therefore it wouldn't be able to share local cache. at least this is the case on consumption plan

Comment: Totally understood. I don’t need a full share, just opportunistic sharing to reduce needing to initialize some data by an order of magnitude or so. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: "opportunitistic share"  - just learned new terminology AWESOME

Comment: haha, I'm just a wordsmith

Comment: The point of "Serverless Services" is to not have a server. By using "temp disk storage" you acknowledge there is a server which is the entire antithesis of serverless services. You put a 500 point bounty on a question that has no answer. Quit treating serverless services as something they aren't. You want a server with temp storage? Then get a hosting plan on GoDaddy and stay out of the cloud.

Comment: totally agree, @Andy, but sometimes the boss says "just do it this way"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1**
Yes, it is secure. The Function host process runs inside a sandbox. All access data stored to `D:\local` is self-contained and isolated to the processes within the sandbox. Kindly see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

**Answer to Question 2**
The data in `D:\local\Temp` exists as long as the Function host process is alive. The Functions host process can be recycled at any time due to unexpected events such as unhandled exceptions, timeouts, hitting resource usage limits for your plan. As long as your workflow accounts for the fact that the data stored in `D:\local\Temp` is ephemeral, then the answer is a 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will answer your question :

[image]

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) for more details.

Also, when Folder/Files when created via code inside the “Temp” folder; you cannot view them when you visit KUDU site. But you can use those files/ folders.

How to view the files/ folders if created via KUDU?
We will need to add - WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION = true in Configuration(app settings).

Note:- Another important note is that the Main site and the scm site do not share temp files. So if you write some files there from your site, you will not see them from Kudu Console (and vice versa).
You can make them use the same temp space if you disable separation (via WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION).
But note that this is a legacy flag, and its use is not recommended/supported.
(ref : shared document link)

Comment: Thanks - This is actually the same thing that I linked to in my question. Unfortunately i does not answer whether the solution is still supported since the release of durable functions, and what the security characteristics of the directories are specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Security implications depend on the level of isolation you are seeking.

1. In shared app-service plan or consumption plan you need to trust the sandbox isolation. This is not an isolated microvm like AWS lambda.
2. If you have your own app-service plan then you need to trust the VM hypervisor isolation of your app-service plan.
3. If you are really paranoid or running healtcare application, then you likely need to run your function in a ASE plan.

Reasonable solution is one where the cost is not exceeding the worth of data you are protecting :)