# Trouble to deploy azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm having trouble when trying to deploy via GitHub actions integration in the Azure Function.

The workflow message returns me:

Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file `D:\\local\\Temp\\zipdeploy\\opldrff.zip` (178.92 MB) to `D:\\local\\Temp\\zipdeploy\\extracted`

There is not enough space on the `disk.\\r\\n`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1984#issuecomment-628808491) the storage capacity for Azure Functions (in Consumption plan) is 1 GB.

It looks like this new deployment caused it to go over this limit. I presume earlier deployments went OK, correct?

The data in `local/Temp` folder should only exists as long as the functions worker process is active ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168760/112544)). So if you're on Consumption plan, and the function hasn't been deployed or triggered in the last +/-20 minutes it should be removed automatically.

#### Resolution

To enforce the data to be cleaned up I suggest you either:

1. Delete the existing function app resource completely and create a new one (this would be the quickest).
2. Use [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to remove the previous deployment files via the portal > Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go > Debug Console > CMD/PowerShell. Now you can manually navigate the system folder structure and remove files, or use a script to remove files.

I have minimum sample of a workflow that deploys a .NET 6 based Azure Function in [this repo](https://github.com/marcduiker/functionapp-deployment-dotnet6), in case you have doubts on the GitHub Action configuration itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to log in to your azure app service using ssh and delete all the files in deployments and wwwroot folders.